# UI controls to get multiple time intervals during 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, user-experience

The website I'm developing needs the user to input multiple time intervals during  a day (24 hours).
The most intuitive way to do this I can think of is a control similar to a slider range, but with multiple ranges. 
A bar with numbers 0 to 23 on it, and each hour divided into 4 (00,15,30,45) parts.
mousedown: start marking
mouseup: stop marking

There is one important problem, though: It will definitely not work smoothly on smartphone browsers because of the small screen size (I should also replace mouse events with touch counterparts.)

So what's your suggestion to give the user the best UX for entering time spans? I don't like using text inputs because they seem so traditional. I want to be a little more creative while keeping device compatibility in mind.

Comment: How about having multiple slider bars, one for each range. That way it should work  OK on smaller devices too. Plus if your sliders have the align to markers (0, 15, 30, 60 markers) feature, usability won't be bad either.

Comment: I don't think this will alleviate the problem. 24 hours and 4 markers for each one, so 72 cells. A small screen is about 350pxs, so each cell can be at most 4px considering the page padding etc. Since finger touching does not have the precision of a mouse, this will not be easy for the user to highlight a range on the bar, be it one range or multiple ranges.